# HP ProBook 855 G2 wireless problem in 12.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, hp, realtek

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my laptop HP ProBook 855 G2, I found that my wireless network wasn't working. I noticed many people had the same problem, all of them having the same card RealTek RTL8723be (it shows as b723 with `lspci`). I already tried the following suggestion:

1. Pull the repository at https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new
   from a working computer and copy it to a USB stick.
2. In the computer to be fixed, load stick and `cd` to folder. Then run:

   ```
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo modprobe rtl8723be
   ```
3. At this point, the wireless network will be enabled, but it won't
   find any APs to connect with. I have tried tweaking the driver
   options as suggested in many places:

   ```
   echo "options rtl8723 ips=0 fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
   ```

But this didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Update question precisely with your kernel version and loaded modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching further, the solution for my laptop in particular was to put the option `msi=1` in the `rtl8723be.conf` file. Just to summarize the whole steps:

1. Pull the repository at https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new from
   a working computer and copy it to a USB stick.
2. In the computer to be fixed, load stick and `cd` to folder. Then run:

   ```
   make 
   sudo make install 
   sudo modprobe rtl8723be
   ```
3. At this point, the wireless network will be enabled, but it won't
   find any APs to connect with. Adding `msi=1` to `rtl8723be.conf` fixed this problem:

   ```
   echo "options rtl8723 msi=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
   ```

I guess different laptop models need different driver parameters, even though the wireless card is the same.

Note: the driver may break after some software upgrades, in which case just repeat step 2.