# ubuntu 15 on hp pavillion 15 with realtek rtl8723be, weak wifi signal

Tags: drivers, realtek, hp-pavilion, realtek-wireless

I suppose you will assume this question as a duplicate and probably will ban it, but believe me I tried almost everything I could find on this forum and beyond but nothing helped. Please help me with this weird problem, laptop is brand new. WiFi signal is very weak, even when I put it next to adapter, it disconnects after logout/sleep and needs reboot to reconnect. 
Tried following solutions:
lfwinger/rtlwifi_new,
rtl8723be.conf in /etc/modprobe.d/...but none of this solutions has any effect.

```
wlan0 IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:"one13" 
Mode:Managed Frequency:2.467 GHz Access Point: 50:2E:5C:EE:D0:E1 
Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s Tx-Power=20 dBm 
Retry short limit:7 RTS thr=2347 B Fragment thr:off Encryption key:off 
Power Management:off 
Link Quality=40/70 Signal level=-70 dBm 
Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0 
Tx excessive retries:0 Invalid misc:1088 Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Two items:  1)  Is your laptop getting hot  2)  can you tell me the output of `iw reg get`

Comment: thanks for reply. laptop temperature is ok. here is output:

Comment: country IN: DFS-JP
        (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS
        (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A)

Comment: K - and can you append the output of `iwconfig` to your question?  I think that your country code may be limiting the transmit power, which you are interpreting as a weak signal.

Comment: There is some information on the subject at [this link](http://true-random.com/homepage/projects/wifi/empw3.html)

Comment: wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"one13"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.467 GHz  Access Point: 50:2E:5C:EE:D0:E1   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1088   Missed beacon:0

Comment: I tried changing the country to Spain(where I am now),  but still no effect

Comment: For people still having problems, please refer to the link below. The solution works great. Find post by lwta08 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304607&page=6

Comment: The easiest solution is explained here: http://askubuntu.com/a/743467/11223

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie servive](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.